# Sybase ASE Client Tools for Windows and Linux

Tags: python, sybase, isql

I am looking for Sybase ASE client tools for Windows and Linux. I am trying to access the database using `isql`. But in order to use `isql` in python, one must have the Sybase ASE drivers/client tools installed.

The server my code (python) will be running is Linux, and my development machine is Windows, so I need driver/client tools for both environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to this [SAP download link](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html) and search the page for `Adaptive Server Enterprise` you'll find several links for the `ASE SDK`.

**NOTE:** all of the links are for recent versions of the ASE 16.0 product; these should be backward compatible with older versions of ASE (eg, in case you're connecting to ASE 15.7)

Click on the appropriate link, provide the obligatory 'registration' details and you're provided with a copy of the `ASE SDK` package.

While the page does mention trial downloads, I've never found the `ASE SDK` to be limited by any licensing requirements.

Comment: Thanks. But can't get pass the End user license agreement, and on submit gets message: "Unfortunately, a technical error occurred when processing your request. Please try again."

Comment: sorry, I've got no idea what's going on (today) with SAP's website(s) ... other than to say ... 'typical POC SAP website' and 'try again later' :-(  a bit of an overkill but you could try downloading the entire ASE package (which includes the client software) @ [this link](https://www.sap.com/products/sybase-ase/trial.html?kNtBzmUK9zU#)

Comment: Same result (technical error). Will try again tom.

Comment: fwiw ... I went ahead and created a new account and was able to dowload files from both links; I did have problems with one download ... had to disable a pop-up blocker but other than that, everything downloaded as expected

Comment: markp-fuso !!! It was the browser (I am using Brave, and disabled the shields), and it worked. You sir, are relentless in assisting...deserve my utmost respect!

Comment: glad I could help; to be honest ... I've got different versions of Chrome, Brave and Firefox running on my PC and inside a couple VMs ... for those days (and there seems to be a lot of them lately) when some website developer decides to be 'tricky' with their anti-popup/ad/shield 'code'; and then there's `sap.com` .... a total charlie foxtrot of a website regardless of browser!!! :-)